# Shortcut key for refactoring menu (rename, "using", etc.) in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any way to bind a keyboard shortcut to first option in the refactoring menu that appears automatically while you're coding in Visual Studio 2008?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shortcut key for Visual Studio is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

If your using DevExpress' CodeRush, it'll be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>, though this is configurable.

In Resharper, the key combo is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, which executes the  `ReSharper_QuickFix` command.

Comment: +1 DANG that was a fast reply!! Thanks so much... it'll make my life easier! :D

Comment: Oh hmmmm... is there any shortcut that selects the *first* option (instead of simply showing the menu and waiting for me to press Enter)?

Comment: Not that I know of, though you will quickly get used to pressing the `enter` key rapidly...

Comment: somebody can give Vs command for ctrl + . ? Because resharper overwrite this hotkey..

Comment: it should be `alt` + `enter`. i don't have resharper on my work machine, can you verify it?